# SSH to Kali on Raspi doesn't accept the password

Tags: ssh

Needless to say, I've changed the default password and rebooted the Pi but it still doesn't accept the password (I've tried the default password as well). I've tried SSH-ing to the Pi from Mac OS X and Juice SSH (Android) with no success. Strangely, SSH login from the Pi to my Mac works fine. Any ideas what went wrong?

Comment: What username are you using?

Comment: Hi Craig, I'm using the default username which is 'root'. I've even checked the username in the Pi terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kali Linux [does not enable any external listening network services by default](http://docs.kali.org/policy/kali-linux-network-service-policies).

If you really want to be able to ssh into the system, you will need to enable sshd and probably change the sshd configuration to allow root logins. (look for PermitRootLogin in /etc/ssh/sshd_config)

And be sure to change the root password first.

Comment: It worked for weeks with. I've managed to log in to Kali several times both from two operating systems. Excellent link btw, thank you!

Comment: It worked! But how could I SSH before, I wonder? Thank you, Craig!